# Reorder categorical data in ggplot2

Tags: r, boxplot, ggplot2

I have a series of boxplots that i am generating with ggplot2.  I want to control the order in which they are displayed.  Is there a way to control this order?  I have two genotypes and i want them displayed as WT then KO rather than the reverse (which is what i am getting as a default).  My code right now is:

```
p <- qplot(genotype, activity.ratio, data = df) 
p + geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter()
```

Also if this is better as a SO question than this forum then please let me know (and if it is the correct forum can someone create a ggplot tag).

Comment: I don't think a "ggplot" tag will be very useful here (maybe mods would have a different opinion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would that help?

```
x <- gl(2, 20, 40, labels=c("KO","WT"))
y <- rnorm(40)
qplot(x,y)
qplot(relevel(x, "WT"),y)
```